# Enlarging plot in mplot3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to compose an image with both 2D and 3D plot. so far I've done the following:

```
import idlsave
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import *
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1, projection='3d',azim=-133,elev=14)
l = ax.plot3D(X3D,Y3D,Z3D,lw=2,color='red')
ax.set_xlim3d(-10,10)
ax.set_ylim3d(-10,10)
ax.set_zlim3d(-10,10)
ax.text(-2,-7,-11,'b$_r$ [mT]','x')
ax.text(-5,-1,-11,'b$_p$ [mT]','y')
ax.set_zlabel(r'b$_t$ [mT]')
ax.plot([bEq[0],-bEq[0]],[bEq[1],-bEq[1]],[bEq[2],-bEq[2]],'b--',lw=2)
ax.plot([pLe[0],-pLe[0]],[pLe[1],-pLe[1]],[pLe[2],-pLe[2]],color='black',lw=2)
ax.text(3,12,9.2,'(a)', fontsize=14)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
l = ax.plot(br,bp,'k-',lw=2)
ax.set_xlabel(r'b$_{\lambda_1}$ [mT]')
ax.set_ylabel(r'b$_{\lambda_2}$ [mT]')
ax.set_xlim(-2,6.3)
ax.set_ylim(-5.5,5.5)
ax.plot([0,0],[-5.5,5.5],'k-.')
ax.plot([-2,6.3],[0,0],'k-.')
e=Ellipse((pf[2],pf[3]),2*pf[0],2*pf[1],-   pf[4]*57.2958,fc='none',lw=2,ls='dashed',ec='red')
ax.add_artist(e)
ax.text(-1,4, '(b)', fontsize=14)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax.plot(-bxDip,-byDip,'b-',lw=2,label='$\mathcal{D}$')
ax.plot(-bxMon,-byMon,'r-',lw=2,label='$\mathcal{M}$')
ax.set_xlabel(r'b$_{\lambda_1}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'b$_{\lambda_2}$')
ax.set_xlim(-4,12)
ax.set_ylim(-6,7)
ax.plot([-4,12],[0,0],'k-.')
ax.plot([0,0],[-6,7],'k-.')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
ax.text(-3,5.5, '(c)', fontsize=14)
plt.savefig("../pdf_box/fig3.pdf",bbox_inches='tight')
```

Wit the present code I was able to produce the figure reported here http://img219.imageshack.us/i/fig3e.png/

There are two question which puzzle me.
1) As you can see the 3D plot is smaller than the other two and there is enough white spaces between the subplots to increase the size. How can I do this? i.e. How can I enlarge the size of one subplot, eventually decreasing the other two?
2) I would like to exclude the grey background in the 3D plot.

Any help is very welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Change `ax.dist` for the 3D plot.  This will cause the rendered graphic to fill more of the subplot area.  Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962442/axes3d-data-labels-and-plot-limits). You may find some more info there.

You may also want to adjust the widths of the subplots with respect to each other (increase the width of the 3d plot and shrink the 2D plots.  This can be accomplished with [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust)